# How do I display Ionic 2 datepicker months properly?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ionic2

I am trying to display datepicker but its displaying months properly but it does not seem to work

Date min and max are passed from dynamically

**HTML:**

```
  <ion-item *ngIf="showDatePicker">
    <ion-label>From Date:</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min={{setMinDate}} max={{setMaxData}} [(ngModel)]="minDateRange"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item *ngIf="showDatePicker">
    <ion-label>To Date:</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min={{setMinDate}} max={{setMaxData}} [(ngModel)]="maxDateRange"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <button ion-button color="primary" block (click)="generatedReportFn()">View</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the quotation marks `min="{{setMinDate}}"` , I made a example to test it and it worked for me

**.html**

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" min="{{dateConfig.min}}" max="{{dateConfig.max}}" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
  dateConfig: { min?: string, max?: string } = {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.dateConfig.min = "2016";
    this.dateConfig.max = '2020-10-31';

  }
```